# Does a transaction with propogation reqiures new can update a object which locked by another transaction?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-transactions

```
@Transactional("transaction1")
public void A(){
    Actor actor = selectForUpdate(id);
    testService.B(actor);
}

@Transactional("transaction1",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void B(Actor actor){
  update(actor);
}
```

Method A lock actor and call method B, method B begin transaction with propogation requires new.I'd like to know whether or not I can update actor in method B.

Comment: logically you can't even though you create a new transaction because this row is locked by selectForUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not allow you to update with  Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.
However, if you want to achieve this functionality, you can do it by:

```
@Transactional("transaction1",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void B(Actor actor){
  update(actor);
}
```

Read the spring transactional document:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html